# Weird Haml 3 error with ruby 1.9.1 and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm getting this weird error on my windows 7 computer when I am using the html2haml command with Haml 3 and Rails on Ruby 1.9:

```
-- control frame ----------
c:0017 p:-9593720 s:0052 b:0052 l:000051 d:000051 TOP
c:0016 p:---- s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 CFUNC  :require
c:0015 p:0026 s:0046 b:0046 l:000045 d:000045 TOP    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hpricot-0.8.2-x86-mswin32/lib/hpricot.rb:20
c:0014 p:---- s:0044 b:0044 l:000043 d:000043 FINISH
c:0013 p:---- s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 CFUNC  :require
c:0012 p:0095 s:0038 b:0038 l:000037 d:000037 TOP    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/lib/haml/html.rb:101
c:0011 p:---- s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 FINISH
c:0010 p:---- s:0034 b:0034 l:000033 d:000033 CFUNC  :require
c:0009 p:0022 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/lib/haml/exec.rb:559
c:0008 p:0050 s:0023 b:0023 l:000022 d:000022 METHOD C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/lib/haml/exec.rb:41
c:0007 p:0013 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/lib/haml/exec.rb:22
c:0006 p:0078 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/bin/html2haml:7
c:0005 p:---- s:0013 b:0013 l:000012 d:000012 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0011 b:0011 l:000010 d:000010 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0127 s:0007 b:0007 l:000e54 d:0020c0 EVAL   C:/Ruby/bin/html2haml:19
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000e54 d:000e54 TOP
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information-----------------------------------------
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hpricot-0.8.2-x86-mswin32/lib/hpricot.rb:20:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hpricot-0.8.2-x86-mswin32/lib/hpricot.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/lib/haml/html.rb:101:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/lib/haml/html.rb:101:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/lib/haml/exec.rb:559:in `require'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/lib/haml/exec.rb:559:in `process_result'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/lib/haml/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/lib/haml/exec.rb:22:in `parse!'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.0/bin/html2haml:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby/bin/html2haml:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby/bin/html2haml:19:in `<main>'

[NOTE]
You may encounter a bug of Ruby interpreter. Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

And then ruby crashes.
I have reinstalled all the gems but nothing will help. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the `hpricot_scan.so` and `fast_xs.so` have the wrong file ending. They should be `.dll` and not `.so`

Comment: Incorrect, those are Ruby C extensions and the default extension for that is .so to avoid DLL conflicts.

The issue is what I pointed in my comment: the extension are linked to Ruby 1.8 instead of 1.9

Answer (score 2):

Looks like hpricot gem you have installed lack binaries to support Ruby 1.9. All Gem that contains C extensions pre-compiled are linked against Ruby 1.8 **or** 1.9 binaries, and are not interchangeable.

A recommendation to point gem authors is build what is know as *fat-binaries* which provide support for both 1.8 and 1.9 versions of Ruby on Windows.

Alternatively, you can install Ruby using [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org) binaries and compile the gem yourself using the [Development Kit](http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/development-kit)